# Can 7 day programmable thermostats typically be programmed with each day the same without having to duplicate?

Tags: heating, thermostat

I only need 2 settings for my heating, one for night and another for day since we're basically at home all day every day.

We have a ground source/underfloor setup which was designed to run primarily on night saver electricity, a bit like a storage system. So we set it low in the daytime and high at night. But because of the storage nature of the system and the fact that it takes probably a few hours to properly react to weather changes, I sometimes need to make manual tweaks to the temperature so I watch the weather a bit etc. It actually works fine believe it or not - **EXCEPT THAT** the thermostat that came with it is a nuisance because for instance if the weather gets suddenly cooler and I want to set my nighttime temperature higher I have to make **seven** changes ( one for each day ).

I want to replace the unit with a Programmable Thermostat which is set once for the seven days ( since they're all going to be the same anyway )  - however I only see one such device on the web and I'm not sure I can even buy it here ( Ireland ) ... there are many options for 7 day programmable stats and I know they have modes 7day, 5-2, 5-1 etc but none suggest being able to put them into a simple "single day" type mode - though I studied this stuff in college so I know a mode like this should be simple to add to a unit during design and manufacture

**So my question is —** it typical for a 7 day programmable to be capable of working in a more simplistic single day more, or do i have to go on doing seven times the programming every time I want to account for the weather?

Comment: I'm voting to close as seeking a product recommendation.

Comment: @mmathis sorry there's some misunderstanding - there's not meant to be any reference to any product in it - I don't understand - this is a genuine question, one which I'd really like answered - please take away your close vote and let me know which part of the text is referring to a product and I will gladly remove  - it's an accident in any case

Comment: @mmathis I'm making a guess and amending my text anyway

Comment: Its still a product recommendation/shopping question, but the last 7 day thermostat I had you would have had to press "copy" 6 times after your change.  I've also seen weekend /weekday thermostats with with only 2 schedules, and I think you can disable one of them by specifing no days are weekend days. Or just get a modern wifi thermostat (the current Nest version doesn't need extra wires) and you can reprogram all 7 days in 7 seconds from anywhere in the word.

Comment: I thought it was referring to advertising; then I read about the shopping policy in meta. All due respect and I don't hang out here much so I won't argue but it seems strange to me that general questions about products are treated in the same way as bone fide "shop for me" questions. If I asked what "type of hammer" would work best to "drive this nail" and it was labelled "product recommendation" .... well it seems a bit odd to me. No mention of it here either  http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask - many people on SE do their best to stay close to the rules it's not easy on new sites.

Comment: With all due respect @byronyasgur you did ask a "shop for me" question.

Comment: Oh I know I see that now - but I'm just saying things it's not an obvious thing so there's no harm politely pointing things out to new users ( as you yourself did ) esp when such things are not clear in the help section.

Comment: Anyway if is is a shop for me question why isn't it taken down - please don't leave it here on my account

Comment: @byronyasgur Are you seeking a recommendation for a new thermostat, or trying to figure out how to use the thermostat you have?

Comment: @Tester101 neither - I'm wondering about 7 day programmable thermostats in general. My one doesn't have the feature  ( but it doesn't have 5-2 or 5-1-1 either and it's 10 years old ) - I was wondering whether the modern designs ( the ones with 5-2 and 5-1-1 mode options ) also typically have a 24 hour/single day mode or typically not have this mode. I'm also puzzled why they wouldn't since it's would be the most likely mode in use for someone who works from home, retired person, stay at home parent etc - and it would be a very simple extra bit of programming

Comment: @byronyasgur I would think that anybody who was always home, would simply setup an initial program that they liked (even though all days might be the same). Then if they felt uncomfortable, they'd simply manually bump the set point up or down.  Programmable thermostats are not really designed to have the programs constantly adjusted, that's what sets them apart from traditional non-programmable thermostats.

Comment: @Tester101 - yes I was thinking that alright. In my case I want it because our system is a nightsaver storage so I want it to look for more heat in the night and it takes several hours to react. AFAIK many people have similar systems. Underfloor systems don't react that quick so a lot if not all are set up this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general question about available usability features of devices and not so much a DIY question about improving a home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to trade in the 7 day programmable thermostat, for a 5-2 day one. A 5-2 day thermostat allows you to set one program for weekdays (Monday-Friday), and another for the weekend (Saturday, Sunday).  That way you'll only have to change one or two programs, instead of 7.

I don't think they make 1 day programmable thermostats, though who knows what you can find on the internet. You may want to consider a non-programmable thermostat, if you don't mind managing the temperature changes manually.

You also might want to read the manual for your thermostat, looking specifically for *override* and *hold*.  Typically, if you manually adjust the thermostat, it will maintain the new set point until the next part of the program starts. While the *hold* feature, should keep the modified set point until you tell it to stop (*Run*).

Comment: Yes thanks for the helpful comments howeverI think I know most of that already and I've read the manual on my own one several times but it did strike me I should read it one last time just in case since it's been a couple of years since I read it. By the way I think I've discovered the Honeywell CM901 is one device like what I might be after but it's double the price or a standard 7 day programmable and my local electrical shops dont stock it - might order one online. The 5-2 is still 4 times more programming than I want and I don't want to be manually setting the override and hold that way